# "It'll be a very long time before someone inspires us the way Harvey did" meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I was reading the script of "The Dark Knight Rises" where I encounter with a sentence

> "It will be a very long time before someone inspires us the way Harvey did"

I spent some time with this sentence and arrived at the following conclusion,which is according to me.
I broke this sentence into pieces "it will be a very long time before someone " which might be meaning "someone has to do a lot of hard work " ,"inspires  us the way Harvey did" which might be "to inspire us the way Harvey did.

I may be wrong ,so I'd like to know the exact meaning

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote. Maybe it's off-topic, so I'll leave this as a comment. You should parse it like this: [ [ It'll be a very long time ] before [ someone inspires us [ the way Harvey did ] ] ]. Hope it can help you a little.

Comment: Is ***us*** in the sentence or not?

Comment: @Alan Carmack Yes,it is in sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> It will be a very long time before someone inspires us the way Harvey did.

We can at least infer the following things from this sentence:

- The speaker is implying that Harvey inspired them a lot.
- The speaker does not expect to meet a similarly inspiring person in the near future; in fact, he expects that it will take very long before someone like that appears.
- "Inspire us the way Harvey did" would usually imply a comparison of degree (i.e. with regard to the *level* of inspiration), not necessarily the *manner* in which Harvey inspired those people.